# Button not leading off main page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

My buttons will scroll to content lower on the main page but they wont take you off of the main page

The homeObjOne button will scroll down when clicked but the  button for homeObjTwo does nothing when clicked but it should take you to a different page.

Here is the code for my Data.js

```
export const homeObjOne = {
  id: "about",
  lightBg: false,
  lightText: true,
  lightTextDesc: true,
  topLine: "Freeman Ltd",
  headline: "Professional & Affordable Services",
  description:
    "We enjoy helping our clients by utilizing over 20 years of experience.",
  buttonLabel: "Get started",
  imgStart: false,
  img: require("../../images/scales.jpg"),
  alt: "North West",
  dark: true,
  primary: true,
  darkText: false,
  navToPage: "services",
};

export const homeObjTwo = {
  id: "services",
  lightBg: true,
  lightText: false,
  lightTextDesc: false,
  topLine: "Faq",
  headline: "We are here to help!",
  description:
    "Have Questions? We have answers.",
  buttonLabel: "Learn More!",
  imgStart: true,
  img: require("../../images/question.jpg"),
  alt: "faq",
  dark: false,
  primary: false,
  darkText: true,
  navToPage: "/faq",
};
```

Here is the index.js code

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "../ButtonElements";

import {
  InfoContainer,
  InfoWrapper,
  InfoRow,
  Column1,
  Column2,
  TextWrapper,
  TopLine,
  Heading,
  Subtitle,
  BtnWrap,
  ImgWrap,
  Img,
} from "./infoElements";

const InfoSection = ({
  lightBg,
  id,
  imgStart,
  topLine,
  lightText,
  headline,
  darkText,
  description,
  buttonLabel,
  img,
  alt,
  primary,
  dark,
  dark2,
  navToPage,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <InfoContainer lightBg={lightBg} id={id}>
        <InfoWrapper>
          <InfoRow imgStart={imgStart}>
            <Column1>
              <TextWrapper>
                <TopLine>{topLine}</TopLine>
                <Heading lightText={lightText}>{headline}</Heading>
                <Subtitle darkText={darkText}>{description}</Subtitle>
                <BtnWrap>
                  <Button
                    to={navToPage}
                    smooth={true}
                    duration={500}
                    spy={true}
                    exact="true"
                    offset={-80}
                    primary={primary ? 1 : 0}
                    dark={dark ? 1 : 0}
                    dark2={dark2 ? 1 : 0}
                  >
                    {buttonLabel}
                  </Button>
                </BtnWrap>
              </TextWrapper>
            </Column1>
            <Column2>
              <ImgWrap>
                <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
              </ImgWrap>
            </Column2>
          </InfoRow>
        </InfoWrapper>
      </InfoContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default InfoSection;
```

Here is the code for ButtonElements.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-scroll";

export const Button = styled(Link)`
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: ${({ primary }) => (primary ? "#ca1f27" : "#010606")};
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: ${({ big }) => (big ? "14px 48px" : "12px 30px")};
  color: ${({ dark }) => (dark ? "#010606" : "#fff")};
  font-size: ${({ fontBig }) => (fontBig ? "20px" : "16px")};
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: ${({ primary }) => (primary ? "#fff" : "#ca1f27")};
  }
`;
```

Comment: notice the difference between btn one and btn two navToPage values. One is: "services" where is two is: "/faq". May be the router doesn't require the / at the beginning

Comment: @Chief unfortunately the "/" doesn't seem to make a difference whether its there or not.
I was trying to get to the faq page.

Answer (score 0):

The `Link` component you are using is the one imported from react-scroll, which is not for navigation.
You should check whether `navToPage` starts with `/` and if it does, use react-router's `Link` instead.

`<Link to={navToPage}>{<your_text_here>}</Link>`